# Perl mysql modul in debian

Tags: mysql, perl, debian

I have two servers running on redhat and debian. I am using a perl script for taking mysql backups and in redhat it is working fine. When I run it on debian, I get the following error:

```
Can't locate Mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./dbbackup.pl line 15.
```

I googled this error and found that I need to install mysql driver for perl. I installed it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbd-mysql-perl
```

The response was as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libdbd-mysql-perl is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 189 not upgraded.
```

Still I am getting the same error. Can someone help me on this? Do I need to restart any other service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mysql.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-3.0008/lib/Mysql.pm) was the old, pre-DBI interface to MySQL.  It's been obsolete for years, and was dropped entirely from the [DBD-mysql](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/) dist (a.k.a. libdbd-mysql-perl) in 2006.

You can try to install an old copy, but you're better off porting the backup script to [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) and [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::mysql), or finding a newer backup script.

Comment: What you said is correct. I am a beginner and i was not aware about this. I will just rewrite the code to use DBI.